# INSERT INTO - Access SQL vs SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a random question that came up when I was trying to take the Access SQL code for an INSERT INTO statement and translate to a more organized SQL Server version.  Below is the Access SQL and I can tell what everything is pointing towards except for the first SELECT - "SELECT "Shipment" AS Type...I don't see any source it is pulling data from and it is called an expression in the design view of Access.  I have really only worked in SQL Server so I am hoping somebody can help me decipher what the intention was here.  Thanks.

```
'INSERT INTO [Fcst/Order/Ship Data] ( Type, [Acct#], BU, Gender, Material, Description, [Size], [Year], Mth, Qty, BS )
SELECT "Shipment" AS Type, [Fcst v Order 03: Create Temp Invoice Tbl (Invoiced)].[BILL TO] AS [Acct#], dbo_vw_kd_BUSINESS_UNIT.BUSINESS_UNIT_DESC AS BU, dbo_vw_kd_GENDER.GENDER_DESC AS Gender, dbo_VW_INVOICES_SIZE.MATERIAL AS Material, dbo_vw_MM_MATERIAL.DESCRIPTION AS Description, dbo_VW_INVOICES_SIZE.SIZE_LITERAL, Year([requested_delivery_date]) AS [Year], Month([requested_delivery_date]) AS Mth, Sum(dbo_VW_INVOICES_SIZE.INVOICED_QUANTITY) AS Qty, dbo_vw_kd_BUSINESS_SEGMENT.BUSINESS_SEGMENT_DESC
FROM ([Fcst v Order 03: Create Temp Invoice Tbl (Invoiced)] INNER JOIN (dbo_VW_INVOICES_SIZE INNER JOIN ((dbo_vw_MM_MATERIAL INNER JOIN dbo_vw_kd_BUSINESS_UNIT ON dbo_vw_MM_MATERIAL.BUSINESS_UNIT_CODE = dbo_vw_kd_BUSINESS_UNIT.BUSINESS_UNIT_CODE) INNER JOIN dbo_vw_kd_GENDER ON dbo_vw_MM_MATERIAL.GENDER_CODE = dbo_vw_kd_GENDER.GENDER_CODE) ON dbo_VW_INVOICES_SIZE.MATERIAL = dbo_vw_MM_MATERIAL.MATERIAL) ON ([Fcst v Order 03: Create Temp Invoice Tbl (Invoiced)].SIZE_INDEX = dbo_VW_INVOICES_SIZE.SIZE_LITERAL) AND ([Fcst v Order 03: Create Temp Invoice Tbl (Invoiced)].BILLING_DOCUMENT_NUMBER = dbo_VW_INVOICES_SIZE.BILLING_DOCUMENT_NUMBER) AND ([Fcst v Order 03: Create Temp Invoice Tbl (Invoiced)].BILLING_ITEM_NUMBER = dbo_VW_INVOICES_SIZE.BILLING_ITEM_NUMBER)) INNER JOIN dbo_vw_kd_BUSINESS_SEGMENT ON dbo_vw_MM_MATERIAL.BUSINESS_SEGMENT_CODE = dbo_vw_kd_BUSINESS_SEGMENT.BUSINESS_SEGMENT_CODE
GROUP BY [Fcst v Order 03: Create Temp Invoice Tbl (Invoiced)].[BILL TO], dbo_vw_kd_BUSINESS_UNIT.BUSINESS_UNIT_DESC, dbo_vw_kd_GENDER.GENDER_DESC, dbo_VW_INVOICES_SIZE.MATERIAL, dbo_vw_MM_MATERIAL.DESCRIPTION, dbo_VW_INVOICES_SIZE.SIZE_LITERAL, Year([requested_delivery_date]), Month([requested_delivery_date]), dbo_vw_kd_BUSINESS_SEGMENT.BUSINESS_SEGMENT_DESC
HAVING (((Year([requested_delivery_date]))=2017));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a constant string that goes into `[Fcst/Order/Ship Data].Type` for all inserted records.

You would do the same in SQL Server, just with single quotes instead of double quotes.

**Edit:**

In SQL Server you would do

```
INSERT INTO foo (type, bar)
SELECT 'Hello World' AS type, bazbar
FROM baz
```

or perhaps use `[type]`, since that's a reserved word in Transact-SQL (CREATE TYPE).

`AS type` isn't really needed, this would work just as well:

```
INSERT INTO foo (type, bar)
SELECT 'Hello World', bazbar
FROM baz
```

The column alias is useful for

- testing the SELECT part separately
- self-documenting the SQL code (for non-trivial statements)

Comment: that makes sense now - thanks a ton.  As for achieving that in SQL Server, would I just add 'Forecast' AS 'Type in the SELECT statement in order to have that added to each row?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking specifically about just the `SELECT "Shipment" as Type`, and not what follows, then what that is doing is just putting the string literal "Shipment" in the Type column of every row it adds.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-clause-transact-sql